# Modifying a struct's pointer to an array to change the result of a different arrays' values

Tags: c, arrays, string, multithreading, pointers

I declared a struct as follows:

```
struct threadInfo{
    char *threadArray[10];
}
```

Now in main, I create an instance of this struct called `t`. I also create a different array called `sArray[10]` and initialize its values to `"0`".

```
int main(){
    struct threadInfo t;
    char *sArray[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        sArray[i] = "0";
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that if I modify the `threadArray` values of the declared `struct threadInfo t`, then the values of the array `sArray` should be changed to the values that were modified in `threadArray`. For example:

```
t.threadArray[0] = "Changed";
```

then `sArray[0]` should be `"Changed"` as well, but when I print `sArray[0]` to check if the string becomes `"Changed"`, it is still `"0"`.

I've tried using `memcpy` to set the `struct's threadArray` to the `sharedArray` and then modifying the values of the `threadArray` but the `sharedArray's` values stay the same.

```
memcpy(&(t.threadArray), &sharedArray, sizeof(sharedArray);
for (int j = 0; j < 10; i++){
    t.threadArray[i] = "1";
}
```

How can I set it up so whenever the `threadArray` values are modified say in a function, the `sArray` values are modified according to the modified values of `threadArray`?

Comment: t.threadArray and sArray are completely different arrays. Why should they be the same?

Comment: I can't pass in a shared array because I am using a struct to pass in all the parameters for pthread_create

Comment: You should post in your question what you are actually trying to do. Otherwise you just end up with a long series of answers followed by you saying "Oh I can't actually do that because of {thing I haven't mentioned yet}"; which is no use to anybody and frustrating for those trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
t.threadArray[0] = "Changed";
```

or

```
t.threadArray[i] = "1";
```

you are assigning a new pointer value to a string literal, so the old location
where `t.threadArray[i]` was pointing to is lost.

If you want to have a link between the variable `sArray` with `threadArray` in
the struct, then you have these options

1. allocate memory for the `sArray[i]` and assign `t.threadArray[i] =
   sArray[i]`. If you want to modify the contents, then you have to use functions
   like `strcpy`

   ```
   strcpy(t.threadArray[i], "Changed");
   ```

   Depending on the the size of the strings, you would need to reallocate the
   memory to hold a larger string, so would need to store somewhere the size of the
   allocated memory.
2. Declare `struct threadInfo` as

   ```
   struct threadInfo{
       char **threadArray;
   };
   ```

   and once again allocate memory for the `sArray[i]` and the you can do:
   `t.threadArray = sArray;`. But here you would have the same problem with the
   size of the buffer.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 15

struct threadInfo{
    char **threadArray;
};


void free_sArray(char **arr, size_t len)
{
    if(arr == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        free(arr[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *sArray[10] = { NULL }; // initialize all to NULL

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof sArray / sizeof sArray[0]; ++i)
    {
        sArray[i] = calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1, 1);

        if(sArray == NULL)
        {
            free_sArray(sArray, i);
            return 1;
        }

        // already 0-terminated because of calloc
        sArray[i][0] = '0';
    }

    struct threadInfo t;

    t.threadArray = sArray;

    char *words[] = { "this", "is", "a", "verylongandcomplicatedword", "0", "1", "2", "Change" };

    // how to change the values
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof words / sizeof words[0]; ++i)
    {
        // here important to use strncpy with size MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1

        // the odds i assign the values through t.threadArray
        // the even i assign the values through sArray
        // changing the one, changes the other

        if(i & 1)
        {
            strncpy(t.threadArray[i], words[i], MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1);
            t.threadArray[i][MAX_STRING_LENGTH] = 0; // making sure to write \0
        } else {
            strncpy(sArray[i], words[i], MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1);
            sArray[i][MAX_STRING_LENGTH] = 0; // making sure to write \0
        }
    }

    // how to print
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof sArray / sizeof sArray[0]; ++i)
        printf("Word %zu: '%s' '%s'\n", i, t.threadArray[i], sArray[i]);


    free_sArray(sArray, sizeof sArray / sizeof sArray[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Which will output

```
Word 0: 'this' 'this'
Word 1: 'is' 'is'
Word 2: 'a' 'a'
Word 3: 'verylongandcomp' 'verylongandcomp'
Word 4: '0' '0'
Word 5: '1' '1'
Word 6: '2' '2'
Word 7: 'Change' 'Change'
Word 8: '0' '0'
Word 9: '0' '0'
```

But I don't see the point in doing that, if you want to pass this to a thread,
you can use the same object in the main thread:

```
struct threadInfo t;

// initialize t

pthread_t th;

pthread_create(&th, NULL, your_thread, &t);

// here if you do
strcpy(t.threadArray[3], "Change");
// the thread will see the change as well
```

But if you do this, you would have to synchronize the thread with the main
thread and better use a mutex when modifying the contents of `threadArray[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `main` could be:

```
struct threadInfo t;
char **sArray = t.threadArray;
```

Then `sArray[0]` indicates the same memory location as `t.threadArray[0]`.

Comment: How can I create it instead such that t.threadArray indicates the same memory location as sArray? Because if I have multiple structs of threadInfo, I want them all to have the same memory location as sArray instead.

Comment: In my answer `sArray`, and the decay result of `t.threadArray` both point to the same memory location. Your question mentions nothing about multiple structs of threadInfo